# How can I solve an error at initialisation in JS?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am trying cloud messaging and have just put this in my HTML:

```
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.14.0/firebase-app-compat.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.14.0/firebase-auth-compat.js"></script> 
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.14.0/firebase-firestore-compat.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.14.0/firebase-storage-compat.js"></script> 
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.14.0/firebase-messaging-compat.js"></script> 
<script src="/firebase-config.js" type="module"></script>  <!--Firebase configuration-->
```

I am using compat, because I can't figure out how to use the v9 sdk with namespace. I have another script firebase-config.js:

```
const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: "",
  authDomain: "",
  projectId: "",
  storageBucket: "",
  messagingSenderId: "",
  appId: "",
  measurementId: ""
};

firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

const auth = firebase.auth();
const db = firebase.firestore();
const pushMessaging = firebase.messaging();
```

I have all the fields in firebaseConfig filled. And then run it too check for error at initialisation. And unfortunately there is, just at initialisation. Burghh. But here is it:

```
register.ts:49 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'addEventListener')
    at c.it [as instanceFactory] (register.ts:49:27)
    at E.getOrInitializeService (provider.ts:318:33)
    at E.getImmediate (provider.ts:115:21)
    at c.qt [as instanceFactory] (registerMessagingCompat.ts:46:42)
    at E.getOrInitializeService (provider.ts:318:33)
    at E.getImmediate (provider.ts:115:21)
    at Se._getService (firebaseApp.ts:138:21)
    at r.type.a.<computed> [as messaging] (firebaseNamespaceCore.ts:185:29)
    at Object.e [as messaging] (firebaseNamespaceCore.ts:166:32)
    at firebase-config.js:15:32
```

---

I have done what there is stated in the documentation. The problem is

```
const pushMessaging = firebase.messaging();
```

but it is what the documentation says. Soo don't know what to do.
Auth and firestore works and I am using plain JS.

Comment: The issue seems to be the code implementation when using addEventListener rather than FCM-specific. Could you provide the code for that?

Comment: Thanks for replying. I reach out to firebase support and they helped me.